# Grouping a list of list of tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, group-by, grouping

I have a list of list of tuples, for example:

```
lst = [[1, 4, (1, 1, 1, 4)], [7,8,(2, 1,6, 14)],[2,3, (1, 1, 1, 9)], [5,4, (2, 1,1, 12)], [8,9, (2, 1,1, 99)],  [5,7,(2, 1,6, 19)], [3,4, (1, 1, 1, 14)]]
```

I need to group the list based on the tuple so that all the lists that only their last item in the tuple are different, will be in the same group. For instance:

```
first group: [[1, 4, (1, 1, 1, 4)], [2,3, (1, 1, 1, 9)], [3,4, (1, 1, 1, 14)]]
second group: [[5,4, (2, 1,1, 12)], [8,9, (2, 1,1, 99)]]
third group: [[7,8,(2, 1,6, 14)], [5,7,(2, 1,6, 19)]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
lst = [
    [1, 4, (1, 1, 1, 4)],
    [7, 8, (2, 1, 6, 14)],
    [2, 3, (1, 1, 1, 9)],
    [5, 4, (2, 1, 1, 12)],
    [8, 9, (2, 1, 1, 99)],
    [5, 7, (2, 1, 6, 19)],
    [3, 4, (1, 1, 1, 14)],
]

out = {}
for i in lst:
    *key, _ = i[-1]
    out.setdefault(tuple(key), []).append(i)

print(list(out.values()))
```

Prints:

```
[
    [[1, 4, (1, 1, 1, 4)], [2, 3, (1, 1, 1, 9)], [3, 4, (1, 1, 1, 14)]],
    [[7, 8, (2, 1, 6, 14)], [5, 7, (2, 1, 6, 19)]],
    [[5, 4, (2, 1, 1, 12)], [8, 9, (2, 1, 1, 99)]],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You couls use groupby from itertools:

```
from itertools import groupby

groups = [g for k in [lambda L:L[-1][:-1]] 
            for _,(*g,) in groupby(sorted(lst,key=k),key=k)]

print(*groups,sep="\n")

[[1, 4, (1, 1, 1, 4)], [2, 3, (1, 1, 1, 9)], [3, 4, (1, 1, 1, 14)]]
[[5, 4, (2, 1, 1, 12)], [8, 9, (2, 1, 1, 99)]]
[[7, 8, (2, 1, 6, 14)], [5, 7, (2, 1, 6, 19)]]
```